# Vbscript to move an excel column to a new excel file

Tags: excel, vbscript

I got a good part a script and from here I do not know where to start.

In the script below I open a file move the columns and save the file in a new folder with date  and time in front of it.

What I would like to do is copy those columns to a new File

I do not mind changing the way this script goes I can change it completly

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For I = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1

    CmplName = Year(Now()) & Month(Now()) & Day(Now()) & "H" & Hour(Now()) & "_"
    FullName = objArgs(I)
    FileName = Left(objArgs(I), InstrRev(objArgs(I), ".") )
    RdyPath  = "OrReady"
    FNPathLen = InstrRev(FullName, "\")
    FNLen = Len(FullName)
    SNLen = FNLen-FNPathLen
    ShortFullName = Right(FullName, SNLen)
    ShortFileName = Left(ShortFullName, InstrRev(ShortFullName, ".") )
    AdSavPath = Left(FullName, FNPathLen) & RdyPath & "\"

    If fso.FolderExists(AdSavPath) Then
    Else
        fso.CreateFolder(AdSavPath)
    End If

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    set objExcelBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FullName)
    objExcel.application.visible=false
    objExcel.application.displayalerts=false

    Set Cols = objExcel.Range("C1","C100000")
    Set TCols = objExcel.Range("R1","R100000")
    Cols.Cut
    TCols.Insert
    Set Cols = objExcel.Range("B1","B100000")
    Set TCols = objExcel.Range("F1","F100000")
    Cols.Cut
    TCols.Insert

    NewFile = AdSavPath & CmplName & ShortFileName & "xlsx"
    objExcel.Workbooks(ShortFullName).SaveAs _
    AdSavPath & CmplName & ShortFileName & "xlsx", 51

    objExcel.Application.Quit
    objExcel.Quit   
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    set objExcelBook = Nothing
    If fso.FileExists(NewFile) Then
        MsgBox NewFile & " Exist Original File will be deleted => " & FullName
        fso.DeleteFile(FullName)
    Else
        MsgBox " File Was Not Created "& NewFile & " (Did not Exist) Did not Delete Original File"
    End If

Next
```

Comment: I found a different solution to my problem. I Delete Colunms I did not need and Cut and Insert Colunms to correct layout and then did a save as for my first layout Then open a second time the same file and did the same for my sencond layout.

Comment: If anyone wants I can post my complete script or Zip my file and post it  -  Just E-mail me at paulus121@hotmail.com

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept it as a working solution.